# File Upload using recent Bootstrap file upload and mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I looked over some other answers and the solutions there were not working.  And I couldn't seem to figure out why.  This is using Bootstrap 3.0.  All I am trying to do is use that to upload a new avatar image.  The problem is it always comes up null and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Here is my HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditAvatar", "Profile", new { userID = @Model.ProPit_User.userID }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;">
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="btn default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select image
                    </span>
                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change
                    </span>
                    <input id="avatar_image" type="file" name="..." runat="server">
                </span>
                <a href="#" class="btn default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix margin-top-10">
            <span class="label label-danger">NOTE!
            </span>
            <span>Attached image thumbnail is supported in Latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer 10 only
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-top-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn green">
            Save Changes
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
}
```

I have given the file input the ID of `avatar_image`

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditAvatar(HtmlInputFile avatar_image)
        {

            if (avatar_image.PostedFile != null)
            {
                //do whatever you want with the file
            }

            return View();
        }
```

When looking at the break point the avatar_image.PostedFile is always null.  Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: What does the request look like in Fiddler? Also, add the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form.

Comment: @SteveAndrews Not sure never used Fiddler, I'll have to download it and see if it can provide anything.  I'll add the Enctype and see if that helps.

Comment: @SteveAndrews it was the enttype.  that made it work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check the request in Fiddler. More importantly though, you need to add the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form.